# Need help writing query.

Tags: sql, sql-server

Edit: Below is the data that I'm working with. The query that I wrote gives me duplicates based on the OCCPSTAT field (Far right column of data, either C or N).

I need a query that would pull the record closest to the date I define (code does this) but, if there is a C and N copy of the record, I want only the N record.

```
5000    1000    D001    RNT 100 11/1/2014 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    GAS 200 11/1/2014 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    ELC 300 11/1/2014 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    WAT 400 11/1/2014 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    TAX 500 11/1/2014 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    INS 600 11/1/2014 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    RNT 200 11/1/2015 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    GAS 300 11/1/2015 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    ELC 400 11/1/2015 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    WAT 500 11/1/2015 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    TAX 600 11/1/2015 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    INS 700 11/1/2015 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    RNT 300 11/1/2016 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    GAS 400 11/1/2016 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    ELC 500 11/1/2016 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    WAT 600 11/1/2016 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    TAX 700 11/1/2016 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    INS 800 11/1/2016 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    RNT 500 11/1/2017 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    GAS 600 11/1/2017 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    ELC 700 11/1/2017 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    WAT 800 11/1/2017 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    TAX 900 11/1/2017 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    INS 100011/1/2017 0:00  C
5000    1000    D001    RNT 100 11/1/2014 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    GAS 200 11/1/2014 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    ELC 300 11/1/2014 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    WAT 400 11/1/2014 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    TAX 500 11/1/2014 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    INS 600 11/1/2014 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    RNT 200 11/1/2015 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    GAS 300 11/1/2015 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    ELC 400 11/1/2015 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    WAT 500 11/1/2015 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    TAX 600 11/1/2015 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    INS 700 11/1/2015 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    RNT 300 11/1/2016 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    GAS 400 11/1/2016 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    ELC 500 11/1/2016 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    WAT 600 11/1/2016 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    TAX 700 11/1/2016 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    INS 800 11/1/2016 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    RNT 500 11/1/2017 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    GAS 600 11/1/2017 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    ELC 700 11/1/2017 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    WAT 800 11/1/2017 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    TAX 900 11/1/2017 0:00  N
5000    1000    D001    INS 1000    11/1/2017 0:00  N
```

The query is:

```
SELECT
    BLDGID,
    LEASID,
    SUITID,
    INCCAT,
    AMOUNT,
    EFFDATE, 
    OCCPSTAT

FROM( 
    SELECT
    CM.BLDGID,
    CM.LEASID,
    LS.SUITID,
    CM.INCCAT,
    CM.AMOUNT,
    CM.EFFDATE,
    LS.OCCPSTAT,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CM.BLDGID, CM.LEASID, LS.SUITID, CM.INCCAT, LS.OCCPSTAT
ORDER BY CM.EFFDATE DESC) AS rowno 

 FROM SQLDATA.DBO.CMRECC CM INNER JOIN SQLDATA.DBO.LEAS LS ON CM.LEASID = LS.LEASID
 WHERE (CM.EFFDATE < '20170601') AND (CM.BLDGID = '85000') AND (LS.OCCPSTAT = 'C' OR LS.OCCPSTAT = 'N')


) AS d 
WHERE rowno = 1
```

Comment: You cannot make with `Case` because case is working on same row, but you want to check the result set and see that if same record exists with C and N then only returning N, right?

Comment: @RezaRahmati, that is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `case` for this.  One method is to just keep track of the `occpstat` column for each group and then apply logic in the `where`.

However, I think there is an easier solution.  Move `occpstat` from the `partition by` to the `order by` and choose the "N" values first:

```
SELECT BLDGID, LEASID, SUITID, INCCAT, AMOUNT, EFFDATE,  OCCPSTAT
FROM (SELECT CM.BLDGID, CM.LEASID, LS.SUITID, CM.INCCAT
             CM.AMOUNT, CM.EFFDATE, LS.OCCPSTAT,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CM.BLDGID, CM.LEASID, LS.SUITID, CM.INCCAT 
                                ORDER BY LS.OCCPSTAT DESC, CM.EFFDATE DESC) AS rownum
     FROM SQLDATA.DBO.CMRECC CM INNER JOIN
          SQLDATA.DBO.LEAS LS
          ON CM.LEASID = LS.LEASID
     WHERE CM.EFFDATE < '20170601' AND CM.BLDGID = '85000' AND
           LS.OCCPSTAT IN ('C', 'N')
     ) d 
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: This returns exactly the same results that I already have after removing errors (extra comma just before ORDER BY and a second ")" is needed before "d" due to the IN. 

Even with "N" values first, the "C" are still in the data set and I can't have duplicates of the other fields (this is for financial reporting).